# How can I import, Modify and Upload an Android library with gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is my very first time using Android Studio and Gradle. I don't know how exactly gradle work, so it's a little mess for me.

I'm using a open source library https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog  (with gradle) in a project that I want modify.

What I want is to download the library code, open it in Android Studio, modify it and share in gradle the library modified.